# Bigger mouse cursor in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a silverlight application in which I have to click on some pictures, if I hover over them for 3 seconds approx.

The problem is that if the pictures are a bit small in size, and the mouse moves a little, it moves out of the respective picture clicking area and selects another picture.

I have tried using a custom image in place of the default mouse cursor, but can this mouse be enlarged in some way so that it has a larger clicking area under it and not only the tip of the mouse pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're thinking about this the wrong way around. The mouse pointer simply defines a coordinate on the screen, rather than an area. If you want mouseover/click etc to be more generous, and give a wider area of interaction, you should make the *target* area larger.

So in the case of some small image, you can surround it with a larger area to handle the mouseover or click events, for example by surrounding it by a transparent border (note that elements with a transparent background will receive mouse events, unlike elements with no background).